# Jekyll - Setting Cache Headers and gzip

Tags: jekyll

Just getting going with Jekyll - running it on Debian, base install, base config.yml.

I am serving some static resources from a url ( and folder named the same )

```
/assets
```

How would I go about setting some cache headers on stuff in there ?

Done much searching and reading the docs and not much finding. Config setting ??

Hope I can be pointed in the right direction.

Cheers!

Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Headers, gzipping, and such would be handled by your web server, and the exact configuration mechanism and details will differ from server to server.

Comment: Thanks Mipadi, so Jekyll really is just flat, just files to be scooped up by something else ??

Comment: @RobSedge: Basically, yeah. It has an internal web server, but that's only for development purposes.

Comment: that is ace! I will just point my webserver at it. I had a conflict going on with the thought of running two servers actually, Jekyll's place makes sense now. Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 1):

One great alternative is the s3_website script (https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/s3_website). It syncs your static files with S3 from AWS and can set headers and also gzip selected files. It works really nice and does all with one command.